# Unity, C#- Randomly select from collection of prefabs for queue rather than spawning?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, queue

I'm pretty new to C# and Unity here and following this tutorial here - http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/runner/

In the tutorial, the creator creates a queue of objects by spawning cubes with a variable x size and resizing as well as repositioning these cubes in a recycle function:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class PlatformManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform prefab;
    public int numberOfObjects;
    public float recycleOffset;
    public Vector3 startPosition;
    public Vector3 minSize, maxSize, minGap, maxGap;
    public float minY, maxY;
    public Material[] materials;
    public PhysicMaterial[] physicMaterials;
    public PhysicMaterial noFrictionMaterial;
    public float spawnPosChance;

    public Booster booster;
    public AnimalSpawn animalSpawner;
    public EnemySpawn enemySpawner;

    private Vector3 nextPosition;
    private Vector3 objectSpawnPos;
    private Queue<Transform> objectQueue;

    public float chance;

    void Start () {
        GameEventManager.GameStart += GameStart;
        GameEventManager.GameOver += GameOver;
        objectQueue = new Queue<Transform>(numberOfObjects);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++) {
            objectQueue.Enqueue((Transform)Instantiate(
                prefab, new Vector3(0f, 0f, -100f), Quaternion.identity));
        }
        enabled = false;
    }

    void Update () {
        if(objectQueue.Peek().localPosition.x + recycleOffset < Runner.distanceTraveled){
            Recycle();
        }
    }

    private void Recycle () {

        Vector3 scale = new Vector3(
            Random.Range(minSize.x, maxSize.x),
            Random.Range(minSize.y, maxSize.y),
            Random.Range(minSize.z, maxSize.z));

        Vector3 position = nextPosition;
        position.x += scale.x * 0.5f;
        position.y += scale.y * 0.5f;

        //Debug.Log (position);

        Transform o = objectQueue.Dequeue();
        o.localScale = scale;
        o.localPosition = position;
        o.gameObject.SetActive (true);

        int materialIndex = Random.Range(0, materials.Length);
        o.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = materials[materialIndex];
        o.GetComponent<Collider> ().material = noFrictionMaterial;
        //o.GetComponent<Collider>().material = physicMaterials[materialIndex]; //Dont randomize materials

        objectQueue.Enqueue (o);

        if (chance >= Random.Range (0f, 100f)) {
            o.gameObject.SetActive (false); //randomize platform appearance
        }

        //Randomize where objects spawn
        if (o.gameObject.active) {
            if (spawnPosChance >= Random.Range (0f, 100f)) {
                objectSpawnPos = position;
            } else {
                objectSpawnPos = new Vector3 (position.x,-4f,0f);
            }
        } else {
            objectSpawnPos = new Vector3 (position.x,-6f,0f);
        }

        booster.SpawnIfAvailable(objectSpawnPos);

        animalSpawner.SpawnAnimal (objectSpawnPos); 
        enemySpawner.Spawn (objectSpawnPos);

        nextPosition += new Vector3(
            Random.Range(minGap.x, maxGap.x) + scale.x,
            Random.Range(minGap.y, maxGap.y),
            Random.Range(minGap.z, maxGap.z));

        if(nextPosition.y < minY){
            nextPosition.y = minY + maxGap.y;
        }
        else if(nextPosition.y > maxY){
            nextPosition.y = maxY - maxGap.y;
        }
    }

    private void GameStart () {
        nextPosition = startPosition;
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++){

            Recycle ();

        }
        enabled = true;
    }

    private void GameOver () {
        enabled = false;
    }
}
```

I want to simplify this function to make the queue recycle (just reposition, not resize) 10 set prefabs (i.e. cubes of set lengths) instead of rescaling and altering a cube every time.

I do not understand queues completely and I know how to randomly select 10 prefabs from a collection of prefabs but I don't know how to "store" these prefabs in a queue or moreover how to then recycle these set prefabs to the correct position as this relies on the cube's `scale.x`.

I am very lost here. How can have a queue of 10 randomly selected SET (not scaled or altered in size) prefabs recycle or be repositioned? Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like what you need is a `Dictionary<float, Queue<Transform>>` where `scale.x` is the key.

Comment: Ok. Could you provide an example of how to use this in the script?

Comment: Never used a dictionary before

Comment: I'd rather not just feed you code that you're not going to understand. There's tons and tons of documentation on dictionaries and queues. Doing research on C# generic collections will take you a long way. Here's a good primer: http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx